# Unable to convert Python script to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am very new to Python and tkinter, and I use auto-py-to-exe convert my Python scripts to exe files. I did not have any issues with it so far, but today I am at a loss. I wrote a python script that creates QR Codes, with tkCalendar-DateEntry for date field. I was able to convert the script to exe a few days ago, but today I tried with the exact same code again and I get a massive error.
The reason I bring up tkCalendar is that when I comment out the import statement, the file is converted!

Please help!

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import qrcode
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk,ImageWin
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import win32print,win32ui,win32gui,win32con,pywintypes
import sqlite3
import getpass
import win32api
from pathlib import Path



strForDB = os.getcwd() + '\DBINFO.txt'
print(strForDB)
openDBFile = open(strForDB, 'r')
currentDirForDB = openDBFile.read()


def printQRCode():
    startPrint.config(state='disabled')
    if len(txt_GS1.get())!=0 and len(txt_GS1.get())==7 and str(txt_GS1.get()).isdigit() and len(strainDropDown.get())!=0 and len(str(packedOnCalendar.get_date()))!=0 and len(txt_Qty.get())!=0 and len(sizeDropDown.get())!=0 and len(printQty.get())!=0 and len(printerSelect.get())!=0:
        qtyVal=int(txt_Qty.get())
        printedLabels=int(printQty.get())

        if qtyVal<0 or printedLabels<0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error","Negative values are not allowed. No labels printed!")
            return
        else:
            if len(strain2DropDown.get())!=0:
                qrString=str(txt_GS1.get())+"|S1:"+str(strainDropDown.get())+"|S2:"+str(strain2DropDown.get())+"|PkDt:"+str(packedOnCalendar.get_date())+"|Q:" + str(txt_Qty.get()) + "|S:"+str(sizeDropDown.get())
            else:
                qrString=str(txt_GS1.get())+"|S1:"+str(strainDropDown.get())+"|S2:N/A"+str(strain2DropDown.get())+"|PkDt:"+str(packedOnCalendar.get_date())+"|Q:" + str(txt_Qty.get()) + "|S:"+str(sizeDropDown.get())
            #qrString="Lot-AV"+str(yearVal)+str(strainDropDown.get())+str(txt_Lot.get())+str(txt_Suffix.get())+"|Date:"+str(packedOnCalendar.get_date())+" |Qty:" + str(txt_Qty.get()) + "|Size:"+str(sizeDropDown.get())
            i=0
            for i in range(printedLabels):
                if os.path.exists('QRCode.bmp'):
                    os.remove('QRCode.bmp')
                time.sleep(1)
                img = qrcode.make(qrString+'|'+getpass.getuser()+"|PDT:"+str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
                newsize = (100,100)
                img = img.resize(newsize)
                img.save('QRCode.bmp')


                filename=os.getcwd()+'\QRCode.bmp'
                printer_name=printerSelect.get()
#####################################################################

            #####################################################################
            # printable area
                horzrez = 8
                vertres = 10
                # DPI
                logpixelsx = 203
                logpixelsy = 203
                # Total area
                physicalwidth = 10
                physicalheight = 10
                # physical offset x/y--> left/top margin
                physicaloffsetx = 600
                physicaloffsety = 500
                dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
                dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)

                bmp = Image.open(filename)
                # newsize = (10,10)
                # bmp=bmp.resize(newsize)
                # print(bmp)
                printable_area = dc.GetDeviceCaps(horzrez), dc.GetDeviceCaps(vertres)
                printer_size = dc.GetDeviceCaps(physicalwidth), dc.GetDeviceCaps(physicalheight)
                printer_margins = dc.GetDeviceCaps(physicaloffsetx), dc.GetDeviceCaps(physicaloffsety)

                ratios = [1.0 * printable_area[0] / bmp.size[0], 1.0 * printable_area[1] / bmp.size[1]]
                scale = min(ratios)
                dc.StartDoc(filename)
                dc.StartPage()
                dib = ImageWin.Dib(bmp)
                scaled_width, scaled_height = [int(scale * i) for i in bmp.size]
                x1 = int((printer_size[0] - scaled_width) / 400)
                y1 = int((printer_size[1] - scaled_height) / 400)
                x2 = x1 + scaled_width
                y2 = y1 + scaled_height
                dib.draw(dc.GetHandleOutput(), (x1, y1, x2, y2))
                dc.EndPage()
                dc.EndDoc()
                dc.DeleteDC()

            txt_GS1.delete(0,END)
            strainDropDown.set("")
            strain2DropDown.config(state='readonly')
            strain2DropDown.set("")
            strain2DropDown.config(state='disable')
            packedOnCalendar.set_date(datetime.now())
            txt_Qty.delete(0,END)
            sizeDropDown.set("")
            printQty.delete(0,END)
            printerSelect.set("")
            startPrint.config(state='normal')







    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!","Invalid entries made, no labels printed!")
        startPrint.config(state='normal')
        return

dbPath = currentDirForDB
con = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
cur = con.cursor()
allStrains=cur.execute("SELECT Strain FROM AllStrains").fetchall()
allSizes=cur.execute("SELECT SizeString FROM AllSizes").fetchall()
allStrainsList=[]
allSizesList=[]


for item in range(len(allStrains)):
    allStrainsList.append(allStrains[item])

for item in range(len(allSizes)):
    allSizesList.append(allSizes[item])

root =Tk()
root.title("QR Code Generator/Printer")
root.geometry('700x300+300+80')
lb_GS1=Label(root,text="GS1: ").grid(row=1,column=0)
lb_Strain=Label(root,text="Strain").grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10)
lb_Strain2 = Label(root,text="Strain II").grid(row=0,column=3,padx=10)

lb_YearInstruction=Label(root,text="(7 Digits)").grid(row=2,column=1)

txt_GS1 = Entry(root,width=10)
txt_GS1.grid(row=1,column=1)
strainDropDown = ttk.Combobox(root,values=allStrainsList,state='readonly',width=5)
strainDropDown.grid(row=1,column=2)
strain2DropDown = ttk.Combobox(root,state='disable',width=10)
strain2DropDown.grid(row=1,column=3)



yearList=[]
monthList=[]
dayList=[]
lb_YearPacked = Label(root,text="Packed on Date").grid(row=0,column=6)
packedOnCalendar=DateEntry(root,state='readonly')
packedOnCalendar.grid(row=1,column=6)

lb_Qty = Label(root,text="Quantity").grid(row=0,column=8)
txt_Qty = Entry(root,width=5)
txt_Qty.grid(row=1,column=8)
lb_QtyInstructions=Label(root,text="Integers\nOnly").grid(row=2,column=8)
lb_Size=Label(root,text="Size").grid(row=0,column=10)
sizeDropDown=ttk.Combobox(root,width=8,state='readonly',values=allSizes)
sizeDropDown.grid(row=1,column=10)
printQty= Entry(root,width=6)
printQty.grid(row=1,column=11)
lb_PrintQty=Label(root,text="Number of\nLabels")
lb_PrintQty.grid(row=0,column=11)
lb_Printer=Label(root,text="Select Printer")
lb_Printer.grid(row=0,column=12)
print(str(packedOnCalendar.get_date()))
textToEnter=datetime.now()
printers =win32print.EnumPrinters(7)
allPrintList=[]
finalPrintList=[]
for item in printers:
    if item not in allPrintList:
        allPrintList.append(item)
        finalPrintList.append(item[2])


printerSelect=ttk.Combobox(root,state='readonly',values=finalPrintList)
printerSelect.grid(row=1,column=12)


startPrint=Button(root,text="Start Printing",command=printQRCode)
startPrint.grid(row=7,column=6,pady=10,padx=10,sticky=E)
print(type(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()))

root.wm_iconbitmap(os.getcwd()+'\QRCodeIcon.ico')
def fillStrain2(eventObject):
    if len(strainDropDown.get())!=0:
        files=[]
        for file in  os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file)):
                files.append(file)


        if str(strainDropDown.get())+'.txt' in files:
            strain2DropDown.config(state='readonly')
            with open(str(strainDropDown.get())+'.txt','r') as allStrains:
                secondaryStrain = [line.strip() for line in allStrains]
                strain2DropDown.config(values=secondaryStrain)
                strain2DropDown.current(0)
        else:
            strain2DropDown.set("")
            strain2DropDown.config(state="disable")

    else:
        strain2DropDown.set("")
        strain2DropDown.config(state="disable")
    pass




strainDropDown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",fillStrain2)

#################################################################################################


root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.6.6
Building in the current instances temporary directory at C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjltqk5rg
To get a new temporary directory, restart this application
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller -y -w -i "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/QRCodeIcon.ico" --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/BLE.txt";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/COP.txt";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/DBINFO.txt";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/GEL.txt";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/QRCode.bmp";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/QRCodeCreatePrint2.py";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/QRCodeIcon.ico";"." --add-data "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/TestdatabaseBudToFG.db";"."  "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Newest Versions of Apps/QRCodeCreatePrint2/QRCodeCreatePrint2.py"
1426181 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0+8196c57ab
1426181 INFO: Python: 3.7.3 (conda)
1426182 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
1426195 INFO: wrote C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjltqk5rg\QRCodeCreatePrint2.spec
1426199 INFO: UPX is not available.
1426204 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Newest Versions of Apps\\QRCodeCreatePrint2',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpjltqk5rg']
1426204 INFO: checking Analysis
1426205 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-02.toc is non existent
1426205 INFO: Reusing cached module dependency graph...
1426276 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1427088 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-02.toc
1427091 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\python.exe
1428280 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Newest Versions of Apps\QRCodeCreatePrint2\QRCodeCreatePrint2.py
1428870 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
1430474 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
1430477 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\USERNAME\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\miniconda3\\lib'
1432867 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
1432870 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\USERNAME\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
1434818 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
1443890 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
1459336 INFO: Processing module hooks...
1459337 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-babel.py"...
1459546 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
1459551 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
1460706 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
1460710 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
1460951 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-gevent.py"...
1461637 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
1461637 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi']
1464333 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
1464348 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
1464355 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nltk.py"...
An error occurred, traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 269, in convert
    pyi.run() # Execute PyInstaller
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 112, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 732, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 679, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjltqk5rg\QRCodeCreatePrint2.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 420, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 309, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 415, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 396, in _load_hook_module
    attr_value = sanitizer_func(attr_value)
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+8196c57ab-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 525, in format_binaries_and_datas
    raise SystemExit(msg)
SystemExit: Unable to find "C:\Users\USERNAME\nltk_data" when adding binary and data files.

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Comment: Why use pyinstaller? I also had a bad experience with that package. Why not use cx_Freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not you use cx_Freeze?

## Install:

`python -m pip install cx_Freeze`

## Setup File:

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import *
import sys
if sys.platform == "win32":
     base = "Win32GUI"

imodules=['tkinter'] #modules to include

emodules=[] ###modules to NOT include
            #(useful if a module is forcefully installed
            #even if you don't want that module)



build_exe_options={"packages":imodules,"excludes":emodules}

setup(
        name= "Application Name",
        options={"build_exe":build_exe_options},
        executables=[
        Executable(
                 "file.py", base=base,
                )
            ]
        )
```

## Build

```
cd where\ever\setupdotpy\is
python setup.py build
```

Comment: It gives an error:
[Errno2] No such file or directory

Comment: I added the sqlite3.dll manually and it worked.
Thanks a lot guys. 
Any idea why auto-py-to-exe didn't work in this case?

Comment: Don't copy paste the 'cd' command I provided. use 'cd' to go to the directory where your setup.py is (ex. cd C:\Users\username\Desktop)

Answer (score 2):

This way of using pyinstaller works for me and others when using DateEntry:

```
pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import babel.numbers script.py
```

I did not come up with this solution. Credit goes to this fellow:
https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/32#issuecomment-431131534